# Spring Boot - MockMVC Error creating bean

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito

Been trying to figure this out all day, wondered if someone could help and shed some light. Any help is much appreciated.

I'm really unsure as to why this is happening, I thought that using `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` would solve the issue

Error:

```
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mockMvc' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/MockMvcAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc]: Factory method 'mockMvc' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc]: Factory method 'mockMvc' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initHandlerAdapters(DispatcherServlet.java:610)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initStrategies(DispatcherServlet.java:488)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.onRefresh(DispatcherServlet.java:476)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvcBuilderSupport.createMockMvc(MockMvcBuilderSupport.java:69)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.AbstractMockMvcBuilder.build(AbstractMockMvcBuilder.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration.mockMvc(MockMvcAutoConfiguration.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3b3c23b.CGLIB$mockMvc$2(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3b3c23b$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e4380fbd.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3b3c23b.mockMvc(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider.<init>(JsonSmartJsonProvider.java:39)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.DefaultsImpl.jsonProvider(DefaultsImpl.java:21)
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration$ConfigurationBuilder.build(Configuration.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.web.JsonProjectingMethodInterceptorFactory.<init>(JsonProjectingMethodInterceptorFactory.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.web.ProjectingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.initProjectionFactory(ProjectingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.web.ProjectingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(ProjectingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration.extendMessageConverters(SpringDataWebConfiguration.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.extendMessageConverters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.extendMessageConverters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:122)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getMessageConverters(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:718)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:525)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:376)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c7ea907.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$3(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c7ea907$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e51d818d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8c7ea907.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 74 more
```

Unit Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringBootTest
public class ClaimDocumentControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private DocumentProductionService service;

    @Test
    public void testGenerateClaimDocument() throws Exception {
        final ClaimRequest request = constructRequest();
        String input = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request);

        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/redundency/generateClaimDocument")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(input))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andExpect(status().isOk());

        verify(service, times(1)).generateClaimDocument(request);

    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() { return new ObjectMapper(); }

}
```

Gradle.Build Dependencies:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies{
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'
    compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'

    // Database
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'jta', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '6.1.0.jre8'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8', version: '5.0.12.Final'
    //compile "org.flywaydb:flyway-core:5.1.4"

    // Dependencies for tests
    testCompile(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE')
}
```

Comment: It's your code is reason of exception. What is there `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader
    at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider.<init>(JsonSmartJsonProvider.java:39)
` ?

Comment: @YuriyAlevohin How? Can you give some context?

Comment: Please make sure you hooked all beans properly, this error commonly occur due to that most of the time.

Comment: Which Bean? I have hooked all of them up - I will edit my post

Comment: @thomas-withers please provide code from constructor of `com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider`. I'm almost sure that there is some reflection magic at line `JsonSmartJsonProvider.java:39`. When constructor fails context creation will fail too.

Comment: @YuriyAlevohin I'm not using `JsonSmartJsonProvider.java:39`

Comment: @YuriyAlevohin I've added the code from `JsonSmartJsonProvider.java`

Comment: @thomas-withers oh, yes, it's not your class. So it looks like some jar conflict in that case.

Comment: @YuriyAlevohin Any idea what the conflict could be?

Comment: @thomas-withers try `mvn dependency:tree` and grep `json-path` from here.

Comment: @YuriyAlevohin not using maven, using Gradle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176874/discussion-between-yuriy-alevohin-and-thomas-withers).

Comment: Looks like incompatible library versions. Probably trying to outsmart the `spring-boot-starter` projects or trying to figure out dependencies yourself. So in short add your list of dependencies to your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum Added my Gradle.Build Dependencies

Comment: For starter remove `mockito`, `junit` and `spring-test` those are managed by `spring-boot-starter-test`. `commons-logging` is automatically excluded.

Comment: @M.Deinum Done that and Issue is still present

Comment: Check your dependencies and figure out what is pulling in the conflicting jsonpath dependency. `./gradlew dependencies`.

Comment: FWIW this issue is very close to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000702530-NoSuchFieldError-defaultReader-when-running-tests-in-IDEA

Comment: Actually if you see the comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177814/spring-boot-error-creating-bean-with-name-requestmappinghandleradapter-nosu it is probably the mssql driver version as @KellyMarchewa was using the same version and said it worked after upgrading

Comment: @RyanDawson Thanks! This worked. If you put an answer, Ill mark it correct and upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a dependency clash on the json-path library. The error matches [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177814/spring-boot-error-creating-bean-with-name-requestmappinghandleradapter-nosu) and there [@KellyMarchewa comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48177814/spring-boot-error-creating-bean-with-name-requestmappinghandleradapter-nosu#comment83360433_48177814) that for them it worked after upgrading the mssql driver version

Comment: This did indeed fix it :)