# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader (JsonSmartJsonProvider.java:39)

Tags: json, apache-spark, json-path-expression, jayway

I am using json-path-2.4.0 library in spark jobs which has a dependency on json-smart 2.x , but the spark jars default classpath folder (/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/spark2/jars/) has json-smart 1.x which always gets precedence and I am unable to use the json-path 2.x library.

Facing the below error everytime I run :

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader
at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider.(JsonSmartJsonProvider.java:39)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.DefaultsImpl.jsonProvider(DefaultsImpl.java:21)
at com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.defaultConfiguration(Configuration.java:174)

Similar issue has been reported earlier : 
[JSON Path 2.3.0 conflicts with hadoop 2.7 Environment JSON-smart1.2.0.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56945580/json-path-2-3-0-conflicts-with-hadoop-2-7-environment-json-smart1-2-0-jar)

But havent found any working solution. Please help.

Comment: Hi @Subbu - Even i am facing the same issue, let me know if you are able to fix the issue.