# JSONPATH - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, jsonpath

I am trying to use Jayaway JSONPATH with my Spark RDD operations. (spark version 1.6.3)
JsonPath version 2.0.0
I am getting the following stack trace when running.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: defaultReader
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider.<init>(JsonSmartJsonProvider.java:39)
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.DefaultsImpl.jsonProvider(DefaultsImpl.java:21)
        at com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.defaultConfiguration(Configuration.java:179)
        at com.virtualpairprogrammers.JavaIntroduction.returnJsonData(JavaIntroduction.java:115)
        at com.virtualpairprogrammers.JavaIntroduction$1.call(JavaIntroduction.java:58)
        at com.virtualpairprogrammers.JavaIntroduction$1.call(JavaIntroduction.java:1)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:1015)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:312)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1335)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1$$anonfun$29.apply(RDD.scala:1335)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1857)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1857)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When i run it in my eclipse , only the json data extraction using the JSONPATH , i am getting the results properly.
When i am using Spark submit, i am getting the above error message.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40954331/json-parser-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-defaultreader) read it , but was not that related to my usecase.

If anyone has faced this issue and fixed it please do assist me to move forward.

Following is the Code Snippet , i am using,

```
JavaRDD<Document> rdd = MongoSpark.load(jsc);
JavaRDD<String> fullFile = rdd.map(new Function<Document, String>() {

                public String call(Document s) {
                    String values="";
                    Configuration conf1 = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().addOptions(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS);
                    ReadContext ctx = JsonPath.using(conf1).parse(s.toJson());
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < charsetNameArray.length;i++) {
                                                values=values+"|"+ctx.read("$."+charsetNameArray[i]);
                    }
                    return values;
                }
            });
```

Also i have tried running it Json path from eclipse, it is working fine for me. When running through Spark Submit is when it fails.

Thanks in Advance
Regards

Comment: can you share your `object` and your `expression`?

Comment: @MortezaBandi : I have updated the code over there, where i am using the getting error. 

Similarly i tried to use the following to print if i am using the correct version of the Class , but when i run from eclipse it runs for me. But when run from Spark Submit it fails.
`clazz.getName(),p.getImplementationTitle(),p.getImplementationVersion(),p.getImplementationVendor()`

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot , and i think Jsonpath is not compatible with Hadoop 2.7 and below.
Below is the Link for the reference :-
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56945580/json-path-2-3-0-conflicts-with-hadoop-2-7-environment-json-smart1-2-0-jar)

Used the JsonFlatten to flatten and then use Map function in RDD to convert into readable or usable RDD.

Below is the Maven Dependency for the same.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.github.wnameless</groupId>
<artifactId>json-flattener</artifactId>
<version>0.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```